# when calling Api, working fine on local while not working when hosted in C#

Tags: c#, rest

> System.Net.WebException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

I have used below code:

```
string ClaimStatus_url = "https://qms.futuregenerali.in/FGClaimWsAPI/api/Common/FetchClaimdetails";

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ClaimStatus_url);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
httpWebRequest.Timeout = -1;

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = "{\"ClaimNo\":\"" + userProfile.ClaimNumber + "\"}";
    //string json = "{\"ClaimNo\":\"CV010831\"}";
    streamWriter.Write(json);
}
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
var result1 = "";
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    result1 = result.Substring(1, result.Length - 2); // to bring response result in proper format
}
```

Comment: Hosted means you deploy your code on a server? If yes server has no access to api or has not access to the internet.

Comment: yes sir, i have deployed the code

Comment: Sounds like a non-public API, you may need IP or hostname whitelisting to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Take the URL generated and paste it in a browser on your local machine. If it fails, then log onto the server through remote access and do the same in the remote session.

If they both fail, then the fault is on the server which is hosting (firewall port not open?) If the local only fails, then trace the call to find the exact failure point.